# jQuery UI date picker using input type="text"

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble making my date picker work using the input `type="text"`. Any help would be great.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkin").datepicker();
  $("#checkout").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label for="checkin">Checkin</label>
<input type="text" name="checkin" id="checkin" placeholder=" Check in"/>

<label for="checkout">Checkout</label>
<input type="text" name="checkout" id="checkout" placeholder=" Check out"/>
```

Comment: What is the error/problem? Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM the date picker isnt showing up when I click on field. Instead you are just able to type anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the working sample below using your code. I have included jQuery, jQuery UI JS and CSS files.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#checkin").datepicker();
  $("#checkout").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<label for="checkin">Checkin</label>
<input type="text" name="checkin" id="checkin" placeholder=" Check in" />

<label for="checkout">Checkout</label>
<input type="text" name="checkout" id="checkout" placeholder=" Check out" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked a charm. Was just using the wrong jQuery library.

Comment: @CiaraSmith please accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)